# Numpy - Overlap 2 matrices at a particular position

Tags: numpy

Good day,

Lets say I have a 200*200 matrix A, and 50*50 matrix B. I want B to be placed on the point A at say (175,175). The problem with this is that B exceeds the bounds of A, but what I really need is for the exceeded bounds to clip off.

I tried doing something like this: A[y:yRange+y, x:xRange+x] = B, but this will throw the out of bounds error. Is there any easy way to overlap these 2 at a position without resorting to a slow for loop.

Comment: I suppose one method is to check for overlap and cut the matrix B accordingly. How might I do that. Also, is another way possible

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a slice of `B` onto a slice of `A`, for example:

```
 A[175:, 175:] = B[:25, :25]
```

It's a straight forward use of `numpy` indexing.

Comment: yes...that requires me to precalculate the overbounds

Comment: i was hoping numpy could automatically do that for me

Comment: It's better that you take responsibility for details like that, rather than for `numpy` to make assumptions about what you really want.

Comment: Which quadrant of the 50x50 block should it put in the 25x25 destination?  Why assume [:25,:25] over [:25,25:], or [10:35,5:30]?