# Insert a numpy array into another without having to worry about length

Tags: python, numpy

When doing:

```
import numpy 
A = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
B = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])     

A[7:7+len(B)] = B                           # A[7:7+len(B)] has in fact length 3 !
```

we get this typical error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6) into shape (3)
```

This is 100% normal because `A[7:7+len(B)]` has length 3, and not a length = `len(B)` = 6, and thus, cannot receive the content of B !

**How to prevent this to happen and have easily the content of B copied into A, starting at `A[7]`:**

```
A[7:???] = B[???]     
# i would like [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3]
```

*This could be called "auto-broadcasting", i.e. we don't have to worry about length of arrays*.

---

**Edit:** another example if `len(A) = 20`:

```
A = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])
B = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])     

A[7:7+len(B)] = B
A # [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  1  2  3  4  5  6 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tell it when to stop using `len(A)`.

```
A[7:7+len(B)] = B[:len(A)-7]
```

---

Example:

```
import numpy 
B = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])     

A = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
A[7:7+len(B)] = B[:len(A)-7]
print A   # [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3]

A = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])
A[7:7+len(B)] = B[:len(A)-7]
print A   # [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  1  2  3  4  5  6 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
```

Comment: I had to read it twice and to test it, to realize it works in all cases :) Nice one-liner !

Comment: This takes advantage of the fact that `A[7:1000]` is just as good as `A[7:]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy 
A = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
B = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])     

numpy.hstack((A[0:7],B))[0:len(A)]
```

on second thought this fails the case where B fits inside A.
soo....

```
import numpy 
A = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
B = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])     

if 7 + len(B) > len(A):
    A = numpy.hstack((A[0:7],B))[0:len(A)]
else:
    A[7:7+len(B)] = B
```

but, this sort of defeats the purpose of the question! I'm sure you prefer a one-liner!

Answer (score 0):

Same question, but in  2d

[Numpy - Overlap 2 matrices at a particular position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541641/numpy-overlap-2-matrices-at-a-particular-position/30541893#30541893)

There I try to make the case that it is better that you take responsibility for determining which part of `B` should be copied:

```
A[7:] = B[:3]
A[7:] = B[-3:]
A[7:] = B[3:6]
```

`np.put` will do this sort of clipping for you, but you have to give it an index list, not a slice:

```
np.put(x, range(7,len(x)), B)
```

which isn't much better than `x[7:]=y[:len(x)-7]`.

The doc for `put` tells me there is also a `putmask`, `place`, and `copyto` functions.  And the counterpart to `put` is `take`.

An interesting thing is that while these other functions give more power than indexing, with modes like clip and repeat, I don't see them being used much.  I think that's because it is easier to write a function that handles your special case, than it is to remember/lookup general functions with lots of options.

Comment: I want to find a general way to do it, without to have compute `len(A[7:]) = 3`,   that should work also if A has length 20 for example

Comment: I think you have to use `len(A)` in one way or other, even if you bury it in a function call.  It's not an expensive thing to calculate.